# How to make the terms in a database search be the user input in code.org

Tags: javascript, database, code.org

"Basically, I am working on an app on code.org and there is a button called: SubmitButtonFreeClothingScreen. When that button is clicked, it opens a screen named "Screen2" which contains a textbox named "display_info". The machine makes a search through a database called "FreeClothing" and I want it to search the a term and display the data of that term. The user inputs the term in a textbox called "text_input1". I thought the code below would work but the machine always displays the else statement. Is there any other way I can do this?"

```
onEvent("SubmitButtonFreeClothingScreen", "click", function(event) 
                {
                      {
                        setScreen("Screen2");

                        readRecords("FreeClothing",{ZipCodes: getText("text_input1")}, 
        function(records) 
                        {
                          var names="";

                        if (records.length>0)
                          {
                          for(var i =0; i < records.length; i++) 
                          {
                            var number= i+1;
                            names=names+ number + ") " + records[i].Name+"" +"\n\n"+"Address: "+ records[i].Address+"\n\n"+"Phone Number: "+ records[i].PhoneNumber+"\n\n"+"Description: "+ records[i].Description+"\n\n";
                          }
                          setText("display_info",""+names);
                      }
                      /*Display Furniture Store information located in database*/
                      else
                      {
                        setText ("display_info", "This Zipcode unfortunately has no Furniture Store locations. Please try another one");
                        /*If no information is found, the string above is printed*/
                      }
                      }
                );
                      }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is searching for a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in a column of [numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

That is, when you call `getText("text_input1")` you're getting back the zipcode your user typed as a string, something like `"98101"`.  But the zipcodes in your database are stored as numbers, like `98101` (no quotes!).  Since `readRecords()` does not automatically convert values, it's not finding any results.

There are two quick ways to solve this. One approach is to use `parseInt()` to convert the user input from a string to a number before you search:

```
readRecords("FreeClothing",{ZipCodes: parseInt(getText("text_input1"))},
```

The other is to convert the zipcodes in the database to strings.  You can do this quickly with the "Convert to string" option hidden behind the gear icon at the top of the column:

[image: Screenshot of the "Convert to string" option on an App Lab data table]

I made an [example project](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/gaX1i6QbW0VZXKOQQ9MzYb7dWU2_2zTF9VTD551GoY4/view) showing this type of search in action.